# gdb invalid backtrace for not stripped elf

Tags: c++, c, linux, gdb, elf

I have coredump from application that crashed
because of wrong index in `std::vector::at`.

I created that elf file via `strip myelf -o myelf.strip`.
Then I run `myelf.strip` and it crashed.

If I ran `gdb myelf.strip coredump` I got:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007b864b918fff in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007b864b91a42a in abort () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007b864c2310ad in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x00007b864c22f066 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x00007b864c22e089 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x00007b864c22e9dd in __gxx_personality_v0 () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x00007b864bc94f33 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
#7  0x00007b864bc9529b in _Unwind_RaiseException () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
#8  0x00007b864c22f2bc in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x00007b864c257b85 in std::__throw_out_of_range_fmt(char const*, ...) () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
#10 0x00006c48e78b6cde in ?? ()
#11 0x00006c48e78beb6a in ?? ()
...
```

All looks as expected, then I want to decode frames #10, #11...
And I ran `gdb myelf coredump`, in other words the same elf file,
but with debug info, and got:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007b864b918fff in ?? ()
#1  0x7a69733e2d736968 in ?? ()
#2  0xfffffffe7fffffff in ?? ()
#3  0xffffffffffffffff in ?? ()
#4  0xffffffffffffffff in ?? ()
#5  0xffffffffffffffff in ?? ()
#6  0xffffffffffffffff in ?? ()
#7  0xffffffffffffffff in ?? ()
#8  0xffffffffffffffff in ?? ()
#9  0xffffffffffffffff in ?? ()
#10 0xffffffffffffffff in ?? ()
#11 0xffffffffffffffff in ?? ()
```

I validate `myelf.strip` via `strip myelf -o myelf.strip_2 && diff myelf.strip myelf.strip_2`, and `myelf.strip` is really file that corresponding to `myelf`.

So why the result of `gdb` for stripped and not stripped file is different?
`strip` somehow rellocate symbols?

This is old debian based distro with such packages: binutils 2.28-5 , gdb 7.12-6

Comment: Please update your question to specify versions of GDB and binutils. This could be a bug in either.

Comment: @EmployedRussian I added version info.

Comment: These are quite old. You might be running into this GDB bug: https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11786. Is `myelf` a PIE binary?

Comment: @EmployedRussian Yes, this PIE executable.